# Different url formats in Laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

My problem is different url formats in my Laravel 5 site on my production server and local copy.

For example, I have the next line in the site's code:

```
<img src="{!! asset('images/logo.png') !!}" alt="">
```

Locally I see the following in my browser:

```
<img src="https://site.loc/images/logo.png" alt="">
```

And on production server I see the following:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
```

What's wrong with my production settings? I use Apache on shared hosting. So, if it is possible to fix this bug with .htaccess directives - it will be great, because it's hard to fix server's configs on shared hostings: add or remove modules, you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be with the Symbolic link. When you moved your code from local enviorment to the production, you need to create Symbolic link again on the production server.

Run command `php artisan storage:link` using CLI.

If you don't have CLI access with your c-panel, you can run the command programmatically. Add below code in your routes/web.php file:

```
Route::get('/sym-link', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

And visit YOUR-DOMAIN/sym-link once.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-storage-directory

Comment: I got [InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace. I use Laravel 5.1.40.

Comment: That's old version, so won't have that command but still you create symlink manually https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an access to the production server's console((( Is any way?

Comment: Ok, I'll try. What paths do I need for symlinks?

Comment: it is documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-storage-directory

Comment: But I don't have directories at the server right now - storage/app/public and public/storage. How will the symlinks help me in this case?